# Pass $item->description to start_lvl

Tags: menus, description

Is there a way to show parent menu descriptions on the first sub menus when using `start_lvl` ?

```
function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul class='sub-menu'><li class='menu-image-container'><div class='menu-image'></div><div class='menu-description'></div></li>\n";
}
```

I want to put the description of the parent menu item inside the `menu-description` tags.

I know you can use `start_el` to get `$item->description` but is there anyway to be able to pass that through to `start_lvl` ?

Comment: You can use start_el and in that check if item has childs, then out put description...

Comment: Can you give an example of this please @RajeevVyas ?

Comment: @Lee `if ( $this->has_children )`

Comment: Would one of you be able to provide that as an answer please? I don't understand how you're saying this to be used in the start_lvl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Get menu description as global variable
function add_menu_description( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
    global $description;
    $description = $item->post_content;
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'add_menu_description', 10, 4);

// Submenu walker to add image
class submenu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if(0 == $depth) {
            global $description;
            $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">'.
                '<li class="row marginbottom1">'.
                    '<div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-9">'.
                    '<div class="menu-title">'.
                            //$item->title.
                        '</div>'.
                        '<div class="menu-description">'.
                            $description.
                        '</div>'.
                    '</div>'.
                    '<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3"><div class="menu-image img-rounded"></div></div>'.
                '</li>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<ul class="sub-menu">';
        }
    }
}
```